# How to add user from terminal but, the new user should set password when they log in for the first time?

Tags: linux, terminal, user-accounts, gnome

How to add user like [gnome does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsDSu.png) from terminal? I mean, I want the new user to set a password when they log in for the first time. But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a normal user with the `useradd` command.
After you added the user, you should be able to let the password expire with: `passwd --expire USERNAME`.

Now the user has to change the password on the next login.

Comment: Wow, it works! Thank you